# Parse JSON response?

Tags: c++, json

I'm trying to parse JSON response from webserver in my arduino in order to turn on and off a LED light. I'm using the [WiFi client repeating example to make a GET request to my server](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebClientRepeating).

Here is the portion where I make the GET request and it prints the JSON response to the serial port:

```
client.println("GET /abc/bze/ HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: www.abc.ca");
client.println("User-Agent: ArduinoWiFi/1.1");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
```

My JSON looks like this

```
{"lightstatus":"on"}
```

However, how do I parse the JSON response only so that I can use it to control my LED? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C++ library to read JSON documents into C++ objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538725/is-there-a-c-library-to-read-json-documents-into-c-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse JSON in general, the path of least resistance is [a good library](http://json.org).

*If*, however, you're only ever going to receive things as simple as your example, you might get away with a crufty hack. Admittedly, the following is *C*, which is the easiest for me to knock up in a few minutes, but I'm sure you'd have no difficulty translating it to *C++*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFLEN (100)

int main(void) {
    char *json[] = { 
        "{\"lightstatus\":\"on\"}",
        "{\"lightstatus\":\"off\"}",
        "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",
        "{\"baz\":\"quux\"}"
    };
    char key[BUFLEN];
    char val[BUFLEN];

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(json)/sizeof(char *); i++) {
        sscanf(json[i], "{\"%[^\"]\":\"%[^\"]\"}", key, val);
        printf("The value of '%s' is '%s'\n", key, val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use a library like "JSON spirit" or "Casablanca". If you don't want to use them, then the above C code can translated to a few lines using C++11 style regular expression. It's pretty simple. Just search on web of using regular expression in C++11 and you should get it.